# Can someone explain PHP SQL Select data to me?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select the password data of a user so they can log in on my website (for a member only website). I have a hash of the password and the username written to a table called "users" upon account creation. I do not know how to select a row on the table, so I get the error when the code looks for, something?

I found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) on w3, but I don't understand what each part of the code means.
I tried to edit the code so it would match my user case, but I don't know how to.

```php
$servername ="127.0.0.1";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "users";

//create connection to db
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users";
$result == $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row == $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $userid = $row["id"] && $serverpassword = $row["password"] && $serverusername = $row["username"];
    }
} else {
    echo "User Lookup Failed";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: You don't need to get all of the rows, nor should you. Instead, use a WHERE clause on your [select statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). Take full note of the [expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html), [functions, and operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html) you can use for those where clauses. Make sure you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to prevent SQL injection and quoting issues

Comment: @halfer I have them hashed before they ever reach the server.

Comment: attach as proper link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to select all records from database and then iterate all of them to check correct user. Besides, you should only select user by username and password as below:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$serverusername."' AND `password` = '".serverpassword."' ";
```

Apart, you should use data binding instead of variable to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This is PDO, while I am using Mysqli, so does not work.

Comment: No matter, Query will be same in PDO and Mysqli. I am just suggesting to change your approach.